# Facebook SDK. How to use GraphUserNode

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Looking through the Facebook SDK source code I noticed `Graph Nodes`: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/tree/cc551f793492fa92ca107d596a6f1e3a62fb894c/src/Facebook/GraphNodes

These look very helpful, but I can't find any documentation online regarding their usage. Is there any way to return an instance of say `GraphUser`. This class has the required methods for retrieving user fields, which would be useful to me.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, from here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/cc551f793492fa92ca107d596a6f1e3a62fb894c/docs/GraphNode.fbmd

```
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

// Get the response typed as a GraphUser
$user = $response->getGraphUser());

// Get the response typed as a GraphPage
echo $graphNode->getField('name'); // From GraphNode
echo $user->getName(); // From GraphUser

// Location example
echo $graphNode->getField('country'); // From GraphNode
```

In my case:

```
$helper = $this->FBServices->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$access_token = $helper->getAccessToken();
$this->FBServices->setDefaultAccessToken((string) $access_token);
$fbid = $this->FBServices->me(array('email'))->getId();
```